# Does a user who wants to use my app (which uses the Bump API) need to have Bump installed on their phone for my app to work?

Tags: android, ios, bump

I am developing an app (for both iPhone and Android platforms). It's using the bump-api.

Now, does the end-user of my app need the bump app already installed on their device for my app (using the Bump API) to function properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bump App is not required, the Bump API/SDK is completely independent.

Answer (score 1):

By the sound of things, it shouldn't be a problem. It'd be a nightmare to require that the 'Bump' app be installed to work on the iPhone version. Though I can't speak for the Android one.

Why don't you just test it?